# TinyMce File browser for pylons?

Tags: python, tinymce, pylons

Do you now some AJAX based filebrowser to TinyMCE which can I use in my pylons app?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the closest thing to what you want is [TinyMCE Image Manager](http://dustweb.ru/en/projects/tinymce_images/), which claims to have file management capabilities.  However, it's not very clear what you're asking, so you may want to clarify your question.